# Updating the status of a bonus on updating the used point through a trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

I've a table tbl_bonus. I want to update the status of bonus when point==used_point. Want to update the status to used at that time. otherwise the status will remain unused.

This is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_bonus` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `point` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  `used_point` INT(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` ENUM('unused','used') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

This is the trigger I'm trying to run.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER xyz BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_bonus FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (new.used_point <=> new.point) THEN
SET new.status = 'used':
END IF:
END $$ 
DELIMITER :
```

How shall I write the trigger that will suffice my requirement? Will appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: It's showing error on trigger creation.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (new.used_point <=> new.point)

Comment: Replace your colons `:` with semicolons `;`

Comment: Here's a smile `:-)` and a wink `;-)`